# Why GCC still optimized something while set to O0?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb, redis

While Debugging Redis, I have compiled the code with `make noopt`, and in Makefile, the optimize is set to `O0`. While debugging, I still got something optimized:

[image: GDB screen shot]

In line 1, we can see all the parameters of `aeDeleteFileEvent`, but when I step into `aeApiDelEvent`(line -2), all its parameters are `<optimized out>`.

Why these happed?

Another question, in line 3, I have list all the breakpoints. Actually, the 3rd breakpoint is `aeApiDelEvent` that I have set in debug file(*x.gdb*), but why it changed to `aeDeleteFileEvent`?

Comment: As far as your second question goes - that could be due to `aeApiDelEvent` being defined as a macro (which calls `aeDeleteFileEvent`)

Comment: @Drew McGowen: No, it's not a macro, actually it's a `static` function that defined in another C file, but `#include file.c` into current compile unit, but this will not affect the result. I have copied the origin C file to current compile unit, and the same result --- bad breakpoint.

Comment: `ae_epoll.c` obviously **had** been compiled with optimisation. This should point you to take a closer look at the Makefile magic going on when building the system.

Comment: @alk: `ae_epoll.c` not been optimized. In redis-2.6.16's Makefile, the optimization settings are global, there was no compile unit use some other optimization settings.

Comment: The fact that your breakpoint on `aeApiDelEvent` appears in `aeDeleteFileEvent` is another sign that the code has been optimized. Since the `aeApiDelEvent` function is static and used only once (in `aeDeleteFileEvent`), the compiler decided to inline it in `aeDeleteFileEvent`. Did you build with optimization on and then tried to build without optimization? In this case, make probably won't rebuild the files, since the modification dates did not change. You would need to make clean.

Comment: Also, type `make noopt V=1` to make sure that -O0 is effectively passed to gcc.

Comment: Dear @coanor, face the facts. gbd tells you something had been optimised away, who else but the compiler did this. And the compiler surely only does what it was told. So something **must** have told it to optimise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thanks @alk(the fact is GCC optimized it) and @markys(`V=1` works for me).

I find a tricky (maybe Bug, because it makes the `make noopt` has no effect on debugging) in Redis's Makefile, there was a rule that will include a `.make-settings`,  and within the file, one of the option is set `O2` optimization.

After comment the line in Makefile, no optimization appears in GDB now.

Comment: You should open an issue on redis' github to clear it out (assuming it hasn't been fixed).

Comment: is this cleaned now?